# How can I use one daterange picker plugin for two fileds?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, daterangepicker

I want to use this daterange picker plugin to 
http://www.daterangepicker.com/ open for two fields start date and end date. Right now it only opens for one field. Is there a way to achieve it on two fields.

Comment: You can use two single different daterange picker to achieve your requirement.

Comment: when I use two single different daterange picker it does not highlight the range when I select the second date.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
$("#date-range-picker").daterangepicker({}, function(start, end) {
    $scope.startDate = start.format('MM/DD/YYYY');
    $scope.endDate = end.format('MM/DD/YYYY');
    $scope.$apply();
});
```

See the [full fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vaknxn25/1/).